# Create a column that should only allow values which end in “@tal.com”

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

Table `LowSupplyNotify` has the following columns:

```
itemNum, NumberLeft, ManagerEmail
```

and the `manageremail` column should only allow values which end in “@tal.com”.

I'm trying to create table which accepts `managermail` only with values ending in `@tal.com` as above question

```
Create Table LowSupplyNotify
(
    itemNum char (4)Not Null,
    NumberLeft int ,
    Constraint ManagerMail check(ManagerMail NOT LIKE '%[@tal.com]')
)
```

Errors:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
>   Invalid column name 'ManagerMail'.

Why?

Comment: Is it because your column is actually named **ManagerEmail**?

Comment: THX!! :) i needed create varchar first right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to create a field called ManagerMail before you try and put a constraint on it.

```
ManagerMail nvarchar 
     Constraint constraintName Check(...)
```

Also if you want the email to end with `@tal.com`, why did you put NOT LIKE?

Answer (score 0):

you want LIKE , not NOT LIKE
also your column is called ManagerEmail not ManagerMail 
and you need to drop the [] from your like

```
Create Table LowSupplyNotify
(
    itemNum char (4)Not Null,
    NumberLeft int ,
    Constraint ManagerEmail check(ManagerEmail LIKE '%@tal.com')
)
```

Comment: Thank you also i have create  nvarchar first before constraint value